# Split threads on several pools

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some code like this:

```
void doSth () {// code ...}

vector<string> files_1; // filenames .txt to get text from
vector<string> files_2; // filenames .txt to get text from
// sizes of files_1 and files_2 are ==

mutex m;
// lambda for for_each
auto gogogo= [&](const string& fn1) {
    // Comupute other element via pointer arthimetics
    // Works only with vector, for, say, deque, use container of struct
    const string& fn2 = files_2[&fn1 - files_1.data()];
    
    // do whatever I need in this doSth function
    doSth(fn1, fn2);

    // avoid doing any real work under the lock to benefit from paralleling
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(m);
};

// start threads
for_each(execution::par, files_1.begin(), files_1.end(), gogogo);
```

Now `for_each` statement execute `lambda` so many times as `files_1.size()` have. If it have 40 it will execute `lambda` in `for_each` 40 times. I want `files_1` & `files_2` to be executed in `for_each` statement 8 by 8 (every next 8 should be called only after previous 8 executed, not everything for once). How could I do that? Do I need to free memory after every 8 ? (RAM is a question if `files_1.size()` size is big, thats why I want to do it in the order 8 by 8 ). Ask me if you have any questions.

I use `mingw64`, `g++ 9.2`, `visual studio 2017 c++17`, `windows 10 os`

```
Now lambda do this :
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
filename3.txt
filename4.txt
filename5.txt
filename6.txt
filename7.txt
filename8.txt
filename9.txt
filename10.txt
filename11.txt
filename12.txt
filename13.txt
filename14.txt
filename15.txt
filename16.txt
filename17.txt

I want it to be executed like this:

filename1.txt
filename2.txt
filename3.txt
filename4.txt
filename5.txt
filename6.txt
filename7.txt
filename8.txt
// Previous 8 files executed successfully, next 8
filename9.txt
filename10.txt
filename11.txt
filename12.txt
filename13.txt
filename14.txt
filename15.txt
filename16.txt
// prev 8 executed, next
filename17.txt
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `for_each()` inside a loop, and give it iterators that are 8 elements apart. Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <iterator>

...

for(auto i = files_1.begin(); i != files_1.end();) {
    auto start = i;
    auto end = std::advance(i, std::min(8, std::distance(i, files_1.end()));

    for_each(execution::par, start, end, gogogo);

    i = end;
}
```

You can write this more concise by using [`for_each_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n) and the fact that it returns an iterator to the element after the range it just processed:

```
for(auto i = files_1.begin(); i != files_1.end();) {
    auto count = std::min(8, std::distance(i, files_1.end()));
    i = for_each_n(execution::par, i, count, gogogo);
}
```

Comment: It tells me that `.exe triggered the breakpoint` because `Expression: vector subscript out of range`. Could it be because last number of elements is less than 8 and it takes 8 so it causes `out of range` error?

Comment: I just debugged it, and understand that it stops on 1 iteration `for_each_n` in `gogogo` func on line `const string& fn2 = files_2[&fn1 - files_1.data()];`. Could you help me to tell why is that?

Comment: Oh that was my bad, didnt fixed sth in lambda, thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Note that `files_2[&fn1 - files_1.data()]` might work for vectors, but it is easy to make mistakes here. Perhaps it is better to have one vector with pairs of strings?

Comment: I just had different 1 and 2nd vectors sizes, forgot to make them equal before starting:) But thank you for idea